# Does GLSL remove unused variables?

Tags: opengl, glsl

For example, my vertex shader:

```
...
attribute vec2 uTexCoord;
uniform float a, b, c;
out vec2 texCoord;
...
void main() {
    ...
    texCoord = uTexCoord * a * b * c;
    ...
}
```

And my fragment shader:

```
...
in vec2 texCoord;
uniform vec4 color;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;
...
void main() {
    ...
    fragColor = color;

}
```

Which variables will be considered unnecessary and will be deleted?

Or better to use `#ifdef` to exclude such code portions?

Comment: The uniforms `a`, `b`, `c` and the attribute `uTexCoord`

Comment: @Rabbid76 ie the presence of such unused variables will not affect further performance?

Comment: Is this question related to OpenGL or Vulkan? In OpenGL the GLSL code is compiled and linked by the driver, so it depends on the driver. But with a modern hardware and driver, it will probably not affect the performance.

Comment: In my experience, yes, the driver will remove unused variables *and* you have to be aware of it because glGetAttribLocation("uTexCoord") will return -1.

Comment: Most drivers at link time will analyze shader and intialize handle to uniforms not used to -1 this is will do get some performance as those variables will be removed from code.